# NETSUITE SuiteTalk : SOAP XML Request - Attach

Tags: soap, netsuite, suitetalk

I am trying to create a request on the Netsuite's API SuiteTalk and I find myself stuck on a simple request to attach a file ( in my fileCabinet ) to an Invoice, see below my request then the response I get.

What is particulary strange is that the format is also like the one I found on SuiteAnswers during my research for an answer.

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
        xmlns:platformCore='urn:core_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'
        xmlns:platformMsgs='urn:messages_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'>
       <soapenv:Header>
            <tokenPassport>
                <account>{{ACCOUNT}}</account>
                <consumerKey>{{CONSUMER_KEY}}</consumerKey>
                <token>{{TOKEN_ID}}</token>
                <nonce>{{nonce}}</nonce>
                <timestamp>{{timestamp}}</timestamp>
                <signature algorithm="HMAC-SHA1">{{signature}}</signature>
            </tokenPassport>        
        </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body> 
            <attach xsi:type='platformMsgs:AttachRequest'>
                <attachReference xsi:type='platformCore:AttachBasicReference'>
                    <attachTo xsi:type='platformCore:RecordRef' internalId='1261476' type='invoice'></attachTo> 
                    <attachedRecord xsi:type='platformCore:RecordRef' internalId='413612' type='file'></attachedRecord>
                </attachReference>
            </attach>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

**RESPONSE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server.userException</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <platformFaults:invalidCredentialsFault xmlns:platformFaults="urn:faults_2019_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com">
                    <platformFaults:code>USER_ERROR</platformFaults:code>
                    <platformFaults:message>The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax.</platformFaults:message>
                </platformFaults:invalidCredentialsFault>
                <ns1:hostname xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">partners011</ns1:hostname>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

EDIT: This the WSDL

```
<message name="attachRequest">
<part name="parameters" element="platformMsgs:attach"/>
</message>
```

The platformMsgs:

```
<complexType name="AttachRequest">
<sequence>
<element name="attachReference" type="platformCore:AttachReference" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>
<element name="attach" type="platformMsgs:AttachRequest"/>
```

The platformCore for attach:

```
<!--  ********************************************************************  -->
<!--  Attach  -->
<!--  ********************************************************************  -->
<complexType name="AttachReference" abstract="true">
<sequence>
<element name="attachTo" type="platformCore:BaseRef" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>    
<complexType name="AttachBasicReference">
<complexContent>
<extension base="platformCore:AttachReference">
<sequence>
<element name="attachedRecord" type="platformCore:BaseRef" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
</sequence>
</extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
<!-- attach/end -->
```

The platformCore for BaseRef

```
<complexType name="BaseRef" abstract="true">
<sequence>
<element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<!--  record name  -->
</sequence>
</complexType>
<element name="baseRef" type="platformCore:BaseRef"/>
```

The platformCore for RecordRef:

```
<complexType name="RecordRef">
<complexContent>
<extension base="platformCore:BaseRef">
<attribute name="internalId" type="xsd:string"/>
<attribute name="externalId" type="xsd:string"/>
<attribute name="type" type="platformCoreTyp:RecordType"/>
<!--  primary record internalId  -->
<!--  record type  -->
</extension>
</complexContent>
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that Netsuite doesn't support HMAC-SHA1 so I switched to HMAC-SHA256 and now it is working I also switch to the 2021_2 WSDL.

For a SHA256 signature on Postman there is ressource to be found on internet.

```
<soapenv:Envelope 
        xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
        xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
        xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
        xmlns:platformCore='urn:core_2021_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'
        xmlns:platformMsgs='urn:messages_2021_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'>
       <soapenv:Header>
            <tokenPassport>
                <account>{{ACCOUNT}}</account>
                <consumerKey>{{CONSUMER_KEY}}</consumerKey>
                <token>{{TOKEN_ID}}</token>
                <nonce>{{nonce}}</nonce>
                <timestamp>{{timestamp}}</timestamp>
                <signature algorithm="HMAC-SHA256">{{signature}}</signature>
            </tokenPassport>        
        </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body> 
            <attach xsi:type='platformMsgs:AttachRequest'>
                <attachReference xsi:type='platformCore:AttachBasicReference'>
                    <attachTo xsi:type='platformCore:RecordRef' internalId='1261476' type='invoice'></attachTo> 
                    <attachedRecord xsi:type='platformCore:RecordRef' internalId='413612' type='file'></attachedRecord>
                </attachReference>
            </attach>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Using API version 2023_2 I was getting the error, "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax". I only changed SHA1 to SHA256 and the issue was solved! :D